# Comments hidden after performing the following:

Tags: bug, android-app

This appeared rather accidently but seems to work a decent amount of times:

Click Add Comment
Hit BackButton of your android device
Click arrow sign to discard empty comment

Edit: Result-> Space where other comments should have been displayed is white for me.

This seems to work only if the comment section is longer that a certain amount of rows though I cannot tell how long exactly.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-G900F

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (G900FXXS1CPK1)

Comment: Not sure what's the bug. You discard empty comment, and... then what? What is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! Editted my question accordingly.